# How to set my java programs locale to ccjk?

Tags: java, bash, locale

I'm reading an XML file inside a product to collects its inventory information i.e. various components it contains and when they are installed. I know from the product properties file that locale of the product is "ccjk". It stands for simplified Chinese for Japanese and Korean I guess. I want to set the locale of the shell before I run this Java program so that it pics the locale from the shell environment. Usually locale is set in the following way

export LOCALE="ch_TW.UTF_8"
This locale is Chinese for Taiwanese and the UTF_8 stands for character encoding. I would like to know the string something like above  ch_TW.UTF_8 which I need to put my locale to ccjk.

quicke help is highly appreciated

Comment: If you're reading XML, the locale should be irrelevant to that - a well-formed XML file either declares its own character encoding or uses a detectable standard one (UTF-8 or UTF-16).

Comment: The key word being "well-formed". ;-)

Comment: All I can see is .. time stamp in that XML file has some Chinese characters for AM/PM which my simpleDateFormat is unable to parse using the default constructor that is with out locale in the constructor. If I provide the locale in the constructor as "zh_TW" it parses properly. All I can get is locale of the product from its properties which is "ccjk". It is not in the "2CharacterLanguageCode_CountryCode.UTF_8" format. What I seriously think is If I can have equivalent code like "zh_TW.UTF-8" for ccjk locale , I can use it in the constructor of simpleDateFormat and that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) there are several possible character sets. The language and country code don't really matter here (except for date and number formatting), but from chinese mappings you want a prefix with 'zh' not 'ch' AFAICT. Here's a list on my system of supported character sets (on ubuntu it's in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`:

```
zh_CN.GB18030 GB18030
zh_CN.GBK GBK
zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8
zh_CN GB2312
zh_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8
zh_HK BIG5-HKSCS
zh_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8
zh_SG.GBK GBK
zh_SG GB2312
zh_TW.EUC-TW EUC-TW
zh_TW.UTF-8 UTF-8
zh_TW BIG5
```

It might very well be that the file is UTF-8 but you didn't get it to work because you got the language codes wrong.

Note that you can also pass character sets to an `InputStreamReader` in java, so your VM doesn't necessarily have to be working in the same charset as your data.

Comment: yeah.. You are true. VM doesn't necessarily have to be working in the same charset as my data. I guess problem is not with the charset but with the language.